# Force YAML Tag on JavaBean properties

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I have been using SnakeYAML for certain serialization/deserialization. My application combines Python and Java, so I need some "reasonable behaviour" on the Tags and the Types.

My problem / actual status on the YAML document:

```
!!mypackage.MyClassA
someFirstField: normal string
someSecondField:
  a: !!mypackage.ThisIsIt
    subField: 1
    subOtherField: 2
  b: !!mypackage.ThisIsIt
    subField: 3
    subOtherField: 4
someThirdField:
  subField: 5
  subOtherField: 6
```

I achieved the use of the tags inside collections (see example `someSecondField`) by reimplementing `checkGlobalTag` and simply performing `return`. This, if I understood correctly, ensures no smart cleanness of snakeyaml and maintains the tags. So far so good: I need the type everywhere.

However, this is not enough, because `someThirdField` is also a `!!mypackage.ThisIsIt` but it has implicit tag and this is a problem (Python does not understand it). There are some other corner cases which are not to the point (tried to take some shortcuts in the Python side, and they became a Bad Idea).

Which is the correct way to ensure that the tags appear for all user-defined classes? I assume that I should override some methods on the `Representer`, but I have not been able to find which one.

Answer (score 1):

The line responsible for that "smart tag auto-clean" is the following:

```
if (property.getType() == propertyValue.getClass())
```

Which can be found in `representJavaBeanProperty`, for the class `Representer`.

The (ugly) solution I found is to extend the `Representer` and `@Override` the `representJavaBeanProperty` with the following:

```
protected NodeTuple representJavaBeanProperty(Object javaBean, 
        Property property,
        Object propertyValue, 
        Tag customTag) {
    // Copy paste starts here...

    ScalarNode nodeKey = (ScalarNode) representData(property.getName());
    // the first occurrence of the node must keep the tag
    boolean hasAlias = this.representedObjects.containsKey(propertyValue);

    Node nodeValue = representData(propertyValue);

    if (propertyValue != null && !hasAlias) {
        NodeId nodeId = nodeValue.getNodeId();
        if (customTag == null) {
            if (nodeId == NodeId.scalar) {
                if (propertyValue instanceof Enum<?>) {
                    nodeValue.setTag(Tag.STR);
                }
            }
            // Copy-paste ends here !!!
            // Ignore the else block --always maintain the tag.
        }
    }

    return new NodeTuple(nodeKey, nodeValue);
```

This also forces the explicit-tag-on-lists behaviour (previously enforced through the override of the `checkGlobalTag` method, now already implemented in the `representJavaBeanProperty` code).